# Converting Propositional Statements into Logics

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Suppose

- A= Ali has passed the exam
- B= Bilal has passed the exam
- U= Umar has passed the exam
- S= Sana has passed the exam

---

The statement to perform is:

1. If Ali has passed the exam then Bilal and Umar have also passed the exam.
2. Ali can only pass the exam if Bilal and Umar has not passed, but Sana passed the exam.
3. Ali, Bilal and Umar has passed the exam if and only if Sana has not passed the exam, but if
   neither Ali nor Bilal pass the exam then Sana passed only if Umar passed.

---

This is What I have done so far

1. $A \to (B\land U)$
2. $A \to (\neg B\land \neg U) \land S$
3. $[(A\land B\land U) \leftrightarrow \neg S)] \land  (\neg A\land \neg B) \to (S \to U)$

I just wanted to confirm that, What I did is correct? or If it is not correct what changes I needed to perform... Thanks.

Comment: Please use MathJax  to typeset your formulas. I did it for you this time .. please see what commands I used to do this. Also, here is a quick reference guide: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically correct (good job!) ... though you need a few extra parentheses:

1. $A \to (B\land U)$
2. $\color{red}[ A \to (\neg B\land \neg U)\color{red}] \land S$
3. $[(A\land B\land U) \leftrightarrow \neg S)] \land \color{red}[ (\neg A\land \neg B) \to (S \to U)\color{red}]$